# i creat a table but it don't be horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

i work on a `table` of names and data is very large when the browser is resizing the `table` can't get horizontal scroll.please guide me write its `style sheet`.

```html
 <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Points</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ali</td>
                <td>ordoukhani</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>mohammad</td>
                <td>ordoukhani</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Adam</td>
                <td>Johnson</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>67</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```css
body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

or

```css
table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: instead of scroll i can use auto